# Is the bread really Jesus body - Transubstantiation?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, eastern-orthodox, bible-translation, transubstantiation

**I've heard a million complex arguments about this for both sides - but here is my take on it.**

There are only 3 possible things in this situation.

1. The bread truly becomes Jesus' body.
2. The bread does not become Jesus' body and its a 'figure of speech'.
3. The Holy Spirit made a mistake when writing the Bible.

Lets be a bit odd and using the process of elimination going bottom to top.

If you're a believing Christian and understand the properties of God, then simply the Holy Spirit can not make mistakes since it is God. God does not make mistakes so whatever is written in the Bible exactly how it is we must take as FACT.

Many protestants like to argue that Jesus did not mean that the bread is his body. They like to believe it is symbolic rather then a meaning in actuality, just a mere representation. I asked a lot of them and they tend to say well my pastor said it or someone else said it - seems a lot of people just believe things they are told rather then going out and studying the actual Bible.

It seems that people are forgetting that the Bible is literally God communicating with humans, smart, dumb, whoever you are it is for you to read and understand. It's not always a huge puzzle that requires an insane amount of mazes to navigate. One example of this is when Jesus says 'I am'. Jesus says I am so many times through out the Bible and not once is it 'symbolic' or 'he didn't actually mean that'.

- "I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father
  except through me."
- "I am the resurrection and the life."
- "I am the good shepherd. The good shepherd lays down his life for the
  sheep."
- "I am the gate; whoever enters through me will be saved."
- "I am the light of the world."

Nobody has anything to say against these yet it clearly states "I am" NOT "I am like".

- "I am the bread of life." - John 6:35
- "I am the bread of life." - John 6:48
- "I am the living bread that came down from heaven" - John 6:51

However when he says this all the protestants lose their mind. Hypocrisy!

Also to absolutely put a cap once and forever on this topic; when Jesus did want to represent something or use symbolic language... he did! Just look whenever he wants to use a metaphor or a simile he does with rightful semantics!

- "Jerusalem, Jerusalem, you who kill the prophets and stone those sent
  to you, how often I have longed to gather your children together,
  **as a hen** gathers her chicks under her wings, and you were not willing." - Matthew 23:37

Why didn't he say 'Jerusalem you are a hen', hmm maybe because it was symbolic.

- "You **are like** whitewashed tombs, which look beautiful on the outside
  but on the inside are full of the bones of the dead" - Matthew 23:27

Why didn't he say 'you are whitewashed tombs', hmm maybe because it was symbolic.

This proves that when Jesus says 'I am' he means it. Otherwise you better start re interpreting every other verse rather then just one and live up to your logic. Protestants tend to think that because they are modern they have somehow found new intellect that hasn't been accessible for the past 1500 years by Church fathers before their creation.

I can already think what some people will wrongfully reply under here and I'll try my best to keep track of this thread and decimate any argument that is put against this one with ease.

P.S - I am not Orthodox, Catholic or Protestant. I am Christian! As you all should be.

TL;DR - Jesus said 'I am the bread' not 'I am like the bread' or 'The bread is like me'. Take his word for it not anyone elses.

Comment: This is a fundamental question of Christianity.  This site is not designed to answer it, you have to answer this for yourself. You _can_ ask about each perspective individually, but we're not going to allow competing viewpoints to duke it out here.

Comment: This is not a fundamental question it's a direct dismissal of logic within the Bible in regards to the word of God. Also how can you say that it's not designed to answer it when there are many many topics on this question here. Also your last sentence contradicts itself - if you allow 'each perspective individually' then that literally creates 'competing viewpoints'. Nobody is duking anything out, follow the Bible and educate your brothers - do not let them be misled by uneducated leaders and false prophets. We must use the gift of intelligence and use it for good.

Comment: the point is, you need to ask the Catholic, the Orthodox and the Protestant question individually.  This site often gets confused for something generic, but it really is a number of specific things.  It's not discuss truth, but simply to provide an encyclopedic reference in a Q&A format.   It's probably not going to interest you, unless you're actually interested in various Christian perspectives.

Answer (score 1):

> OP: Is the bread really Jesus' body?

The [Septuagint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) version explains it this way.

> But I as an innocent lamb led to the slaughter, knew not: against me they devised an evil device, saying, Come and let us put wood into his bread, and let us utterly destroy him from off the land of the living, and let his name not be remembered any more. Jeremiah 11:19 Septuagint

The KJV is similar if one understands the prophet (tree) and prophecy (fruit).

> But I was like a lamb or an ox that is brought to the slaughter; and I knew not that they had devised devices against me, saying, Let us destroy the tree with the fruit thereof, and let us cut him off from the land of the living, that his name may be no more remembered. Jer 11:19 KJV

"Put wood into his bread" means take His Body and hang it on the cross.

So, to answer the OP, the answer is no, the bread is a symbol of His Body.

To add, Irenaeus explains it this way.  Note how the word "is" is used.

> Those who have become acquainted with the secondary (i.e., under Christ) constitutions of the apostles,4868 are aware that the Lord instituted a new oblation in the new covenant, according to [the declaration of] Malachi the prophet. For, “from the rising of the sun even to the setting my name has been glorified among the Gentiles, and in every place incense is offered to my name, and a pure sacrifice;”4869 as John also declares in the Apocalypse: “The incense **is** the prayers of the saints.”4870 Then again, Paul exhorts us “to present our bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable unto God, which **is** your reasonable service.”4871 And again, “Let us offer the sacrifice of praise, that **is**, the fruit of the lips.”4872 Now those oblations are not according to the law, the handwriting of which the Lord took away from the midst by cancelling it;4873 but they are according to the Spirit, for we must worship God “in spirit and in truth.”4874 And therefore the oblation of the Eucharist is **not a carnal one**, but a **spiritual**; and in this respect it is pure. For we make an oblation to God of the bread and the cup of blessing, giving Him thanks in that He has commanded the earth to bring forth these fruits for our nourishment. And then, when we have perfected the oblation, we invoke the Holy Spirit, that He may exhibit this sacrifice, both the bread the body of Christ, and the cup the blood of Christ, in order that the receivers of these antitypes4875 may obtain remission of sins and life eternal. Those persons, then, who perform these oblations in remembrance of the Lord, do not fall in with Jewish views, but, performing the service after a spiritual manner, they shall be called sons of wisdom. [Fragments XXXVII](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01/anf01.ix.viii.xxxvii.html)

Here's Tertullian, explaining the reality of Christ's Body to Marcion the heretic.

> When He so earnestly expressed His desire to eat the passover, He considered it His own feast; for it would have been unworthy of God to desire to partake of what was not His own. Then, having taken the bread and given it to His disciples, He made it His own body, by saying, “This is my body,”5083 that is, the figure of my body. A figure, however, there could not have been, unless there were first a veritable body.5084 An empty thing, or phantom, is incapable of a figure. If, however, (as Marcion might say,) He pretended the bread was His body, because He lacked the truth of bodily substance, it follows that He must have given bread for us. It would contribute very well to the support of Marcion’s theory of a phantom body,5085 that bread should have been crucified!  But why call His body bread, and not rather (some other edible thing, say) a melon,5086 which Marcion must have had in lieu of a heart!  He did not understand how ancient was this figure of the body of Christ, who said Himself by Jeremiah: “I was like a lamb or an ox that is brought to the slaughter, and I knew not that5087 they devised a device against me, saying, Let us cast the tree upon His bread,”5088 which means, of course, the cross upon His body. [Against Marcion](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf03/anf03.v.iv.v.xl.html)

So, of certain Scripture and early tradition, clearly the bread was understood as a symbol of the reality of God-with-us.  The prophets prophesied.  Christ fulfilled.

Comment: This feels like you didn't even read my post before replying with your own.. Firstly I never once said that the bread doesn't symbolises the body - I specifically said it does by becoming it. The point I'm concerned about is that does the bread actually become the body or not. I'm not arguing about its symbolism and definition - that I agree on.

Also you are severely contradicting yourself "Put wood into his bread means take His Body and hang it on the cross." then proceed to say "So, to answer the OP, the answer is no, the bread is a symbol of His Body."

Please reflect. Thanks.

Comment: Typically, those who believe the bread *is* the body don't particularly care that it *actually is* a symbol.  You said, "Jesus said 'I am the bread' not 'I am like the bread' or 'The bread is like me'. Take his word for it not anyone elses."   Clear to everyone your belief.  *Is* bread, not a symbol like bread. On the contradiction so-called, reread Tertullian.  "which means, of course, the cross (wood) upon His body (bread).  If you mean something besides what you wrote, just click on "edit" to change it. Thanks.